# How do I select all text on Android with multiple textviews?

Tags: android

For my application, I have a page that displays lots of TextViews. These textviews are dynamically generated as I iterate through a list. I know that I can use `setTextIsSelectable(true)` so that I can select the text but that only allows the user to select the text that is limited to that textview.

I also create a new textview with different fonts, fontsize, margins, etc based on each item in the list. Is there any way for me to be able to select all the text on the page using multiple textviews?

Comment: If you want this functionality I think to only way would be to create your own popup or dialog menu after a user long presses a TextView, then have an option for the user to select all text via a button. You can iterate through the list of TextViews and build up a master string via StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would have been to used stylized spans inside a single textview.

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/blue"/>
```

In your Activity or Fragment:

```
val spannable = SpannableString(“Text styling”)
spannable.setSpan(
     ForegroundColorSpan(Color.PINK), 
     0, 4, 
     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
myTextView.text = spannable
```

See https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568

Comment: Hmmm... Does this work in a table? For example, I also want to display a table and currently use TableLayout with a lot of textviews in it.